# Vectorize function in Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I have a set of similar sounding names in 2 columns in pandas data frame, which i am doing fuzzy matching using fuzzywuzzy library in python.

```
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

datt = pd.read_csv("H:\\FuzzyMatch\\data.csv")

#add column names for each library
datt['ratio'] = ""
datt['partial_ratio'] = ""
datt['partial_token_set_ratio'] = ""
datt['partial_token_sort_ratio'] = ""
datt['QRatio'] = ""
datt['token_set_ratio'] = ""
datt['token_sort_ratio'] = ""
datt['UQRatio'] = ""
datt['UWRatio'] = ""
datt['WRatio'] = ""

#save score
for i in range(datt.shape[0]):
    datt.ratio.loc[i] = fuzz.ratio(datt.current_company[i],datt.crm_company_name[i])
    datt.partial_ratio.loc[i] = fuzz.partial_ratio(datt.current_company[i],datt.crm_company_name[i])
    datt.partial_token_set_ratio.loc[i] = fuzz.partial_token_set_ratio(datt.current_company[i],datt.crm_company_name[i])
    datt.partial_token_sort_ratio.loc[i] = fuzz.partial_token_sort_ratio(datt.current_company[i],datt.crm_company_name[i])
    datt.QRatio.loc[i] = fuzz.QRatio(datt.current_company[i],datt.crm_company_name[i])
    datt.token_set_ratio.loc[i] = fuzz.token_set_ratio(datt.current_company[i],datt.crm_company_name[i])
    datt.token_sort_ratio.loc[i] = fuzz.token_sort_ratio(datt.current_company[i],datt.crm_company_name[i])
    datt.UQRatio.loc[i] = fuzz.UQRatio(datt.current_company[i],datt.crm_company_name[i])
    datt.UWRatio.loc[i] = fuzz.UWRatio(datt.current_company[i],datt.crm_company_name[i])
    datt.WRatio.loc[i] = fuzz.WRatio(datt.current_company[i],datt.crm_company_name[i])
```

Is there any way i can avoid the loop and use a vectorized form of the function? Each function in the loop needs 2 parameters.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

You can use row-wise apply on your dataframe. Here is a toy example:

```
import pandas as pd
def multiply(x,y):
    return x*y

df = pd.DataFrame({"a": range(1,10000), "b": range(1,10000)})

df["c"] = df.apply(lambda x: multiply(x.a, x.b), 1)
```

This will, in my opinion, make you code a little bit cleaner by avoiding the loop - but I assume that this will not increase the performance.

You could try to use numpy.vectorize:

```
import numpy as np
df["c"] = np.vectorize(multiply, otypes=["O"]) (df.a, df.b)
```

For my toy example, this speeds up quite a bit, but I do not know what the fuzzy functions entail, so I am not sure there.

Hope it helps!